# How can I replicate the same behavior in react router v6?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

when using react router v5, I can get the url and path and passed it to child component

In ParentComponent

```
const { url, path } = useRouteMatch();

<ChildComponent url={url} path={path} title="child" />
```

In ChildComponent

```
<Switch>
  <Route path={url}>
     <div>These will show up</div>
  </Route>
</Switch>
```

In react router v6, I try to reproduce this behavior but its not working

Parent Component

```
const { pathname } = useLocation();
<ChildComponent url={pathname} path={pathname} title="child" />
```

Child Component

```
<Routes>
      <Route path={url}>
         <div>I want these to show up</div>
      </Route>
</Routes>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `react-router-dom@6` you don't need to get the `url` and `path` from any `match` object to build nested/descendent routes and links.

In the child component routes are relative to the currently matched route the `Routes` component is on.

Example:

```
const ChildComponent = () => (
  <>
    <h2>ChildComponent</h2>
    <Routes>
      <Route
        path="/" // <-- matches/renders on "/test"
        element={<div>I want these to show up</div>}
      />
    </Routes>
  </>
);

const ParentComponent = () => (
  <>
    <h1>ParentComponent</h1>
    <Routes>
      <Route
        path="/" // <-- matches/renders on "/test"
        element={<ChildComponent />}
      />
    </Routes>
  </>
);

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/test" element={<ParentComponent />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image]

[image: Edit intelligent-davinci-3bhd0l]

Comment: Hi,
I want to get url because let say I am in `/test/edit` route, when I pass the url from parent component I can navigate back to `/test` because it is passed down to childcompnent but right now it is not

Comment: @Khant You can use `"."` and `".."` for link targets to navigate relative to a matched child route. See this [sandbox fork](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-can-i-replicate-the-same-behavior-in-react-router-v6-fork-og960j) of the above code with links added.